# How to access functionality of inherited classes easily?

Tags: c#, arrays, inheritance, class-hierarchy

Let's say `Door` inherits from `Portal` and has a field `locked` (bool). `portals` is an array of `Portal`

The following code is invalid as I try to access a field not belonging to the class I'm working with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < portals.Length; ++i) 
{
if (portals[i] is Door) if (portals[i].locked == false) //...
}
```

Any easy way to access the derived class?

Comment: You have to typecast it, normally `((Door)portals[i]).locked` should work but it's been a while

Comment: you can write like this:
if(portals[i] is Door door) if(door.locked == false)
this would help you.

Comment: First, don't use fields. Fields are *only* meant for implementation and aren't part of a class's API. Use properties instead. Second, if you want to use `Portal` everywhere make `Locked` a property of the base class and override it in child classes. Does it make sense to say that a `Portal` in general is *un*locked, but doors may be locked or not?  What does the rest of the code do? Perhaps the branch code could be an operation in Portal or Door that changes from one class to another?

Comment: By the way, in C# public properties and public fields use Pascal-case. So it should be `door.Locked`, not `door.locked`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (portals[i] is Door door)
    if (door.locked == false) 
...
```

This uses the [pattern-matching expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching#type-tests) `portals[i] is Door door` ("*expression* `is` *type* *variable*") to assign a Door-typed reference to the portal in question to the new variable `door`.

You can even use the new variable directly after declaring it in the same `if` condition:

```
if (portals[i] is Door door && !door.locked) 
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write like this:

```
if(portals[i] is Door door) if(door.locked == false)
```

this would help you.

Comment: a little explanation of your code and how it solves the problem would greatly improve the quality of your answer